# PeripheralManager class not found

Tags: android, android-things

I am trying to access my Raspberry Pi on Android in order to start programming some PWM. The issue I am running into is that when I compile it's giving me the following error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/things/pio/PeripheralManager;
```

I am unsure why this is. I have included the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />
```

I added this line to my build.grade(module)

```
compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:+'
```

And I am trying to access the Peripheral using this code:

```
    PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
    List<String> portList = manager.getPwmList();
    if (portList.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No PWM port available on this device.");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "List of available ports: " + portList);
    }
```

of which I am importing using the following:

```
import com.google.android.things.pio.PeripheralManager;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add dependency for android things in your gradle file (app level)

```
    dependencies {
    ...
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the uses library tag to the manifest like

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.adc">
<application>
    <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.google.android.things"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```